# This script is opening default browser but I facing issue on navigating url on Brower url fields

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser, default

Code:

```
public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Logger logger;

    @Parameters({"Browser_name","Browser_version"})
    
    @BeforeClass

    // @Test

    public void setup(String br, String Browser_version) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

        logger = Logger.getLogger("Zyratalk.com");

        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

        if (br.equals("chrome")) {
            

            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readconfig.getChromePath());

            //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

            logger.info("Chrome path has been set properly");
            

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
              options.setBrowserVersion(Browser_version);
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              options.addArguments("user-data-dir=Users/clavi/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
              //options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2");
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
              
              options.addArguments("--make-default-browser");
              
            Thread.sleep(2000);
             
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
             Thread.sleep(2000); 
            driver.navigate().to("chrome-extension://bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai/view/popup.html");
            
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            
            driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000,0));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            
            System.out.println("Chrome browser has open");
            logger.info("Chrome browser has open");

        }
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'CLAVIS', ip: '192.168.0.15'
Build info: version: '4.17.0', revision: 'e52b1be057*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [user-data-dir=Users/clavi/A..., --profile-directory=Default, --start-maximized, --make-default-browser], binary: C:\Program Files\Google\Chr..., extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at Zyratalk.comTestCase.BaseClass.setup(BaseClass.java:89)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

*Note*- I want open default browser and execute script on it. In this code only browser is opening but URL is not navigating on it.

Comment: Does anyone have answers to these questions?